# java throw exception cannot find symbol

Tags: java, exception

im trying to throw exception from method,but when i compile the below code

```
class launcher{
public static void main(String[] args){
    try{
        getError();
        System.out.println("Line: try block");
    }catch(myException e){
        System.out.println("Line: catch block");
    }finally{
        System.out.println("Line: finally block");
    }
    System.out.println("Line: EOF main");
}
static void getError() throws myException{
        throw new myException();
    }
}
```

compile error

> launcher.java:14: error: cannot find symbol
>       static void getError() throws ^myException{
>
> symbol:   class myException
>
> location: class launcher

it says something, it can't understand what is `myException`

Comment: And have you written `myException.java` and does it extend `Exception`?

Comment: @ElliottFrisch no

Comment: you can not throw not existing Exception.

Comment: im following book of java v5 ,they written like above code "scaryException,pantsException" without writing "scaryException.java", i thought "throws myException" creates subclass of Exception class

Comment: replace `myException` by `RuntimeException`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Problem reason and solution

The problem is, that you haven't imported your `Exception` to the `launcher` class. `Exception`s are `class`es so need to be declared as a typical class.

## Huge problem

You start class names with lowercase letters which makes your class non-readable. Your classes should be called: `Launcher` (or better `Test`) and `MyException` instead of `myException`.

You can create your own Exceptions. The following is a declaration of `MyException` which you might find helpful:

#### MyException

```
public class MyException extends RuntimeException {
    public MyException() {
        super();
    }
}
```

Then import your new class and you'll be able to throw it.